# Implement OAuth2 authentication with Angular

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, angular9

I'm trying to implement OAuth2 authentication using Angular:

```
login(name: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('username', name);
    formData.append('password', password);
    formData.append('grant_type', 'password');
    formData.append('scope', 'read');
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      Authorization: `Basic ${btoa(`${name}:${password}`)}`,
      username: name,
      password: password,
      // 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    });
    return this.httpClient
      .post(`http://localhost:8080/engine/oauth/token`, formData, {
        headers,
        withCredentials: true,
      })
      .pipe(
        map((response: Authorize) => {
          sessionStorage.setItem('token', response.accessToken);
          return true;
        })
      );
  }
```

Github [code](https://github.com/rcbandit111/wiki-ui/blob/OAuth2/src/app/_auth/services/login.service.ts#L28)

But I get always error: `{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Missing grant type"}`

With Postman I can make a successful request:

[image]

But using Angular I get this error. Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: whats the grant_type variablename in your formdata object?

Comment: It's set 'password': https://github.com/rcbandit111/wiki-ui/blob/OAuth2/src/app/_auth/services/login.service.ts#L19

Comment: consider switching to any well-known oidc client library instead of trying to implement your own. for instance you always add the _angular-oauth2-oidc_ tag -- it's a good one -- just go through it's readme an you are done. one more advice: never use `password` grant type on the web, use `authorization_code` instead

Comment: @d_f Do you have a deep experience with OAuth2, Spring Security and Angular?

Comment: All but Spring Security. And when you use the angular-oauth2-oidc lib, it works in the browser without any support or interaction with your server code: authentication, checking session, refreshing tokens - everything is in the browser. So what you can get from Spring Security is only the protection for your API.

Comment: I don't use `angular-oauth2-oidc`. I'm going to use solution similar to this: https://codinglatte.com/posts/angular/refreshing-authorization-tokens-angular-6/  This solution uses interceptor to renew the access token. In not aware is it better than  `angular-oauth2-oidc` What do you think?

Comment: afaik, the angular-oauth2-oidc's author implemented and recommends the approach with the refresh token instead of the silent refresh. I do not think it's good to wait and catch 401 responses to trigger the refresh. much more straightforward would be to remember the token expiration once one received and start refreshing before the expiration time. `angular-oauth2-oidc` behaves this way. you are free to combine it with the check in the interceptor if you like to

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer: please avoid "password" flow at great cost, [it has been officially deprecated](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics-15#section-2.4).**  But, if you must use it, here's a simple way to do so:

```javascript
// Please avoid "password" flow at all cost, it has been officially deprecated
// https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics-15#section-2.4
// But, if you must use it, here's a simple way to do so:
async function getTokenResponse(clientId, identityServerUrl, username, password) {
  const response = await fetch(identityServerUrl + "/connect/token", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
    },
    body: new URLSearchParams({
      "grant_type": "password",
      "client_id": clientId,
      "username": username,
      "password": password,
    }),
  });

  const json = await response.json();
  console.log(json); // json.access_token should contain the actual token
  return JSON.stringify(json, null, 2);
}
```

This [has worked for me](https://github.com/jeroenheijmans/sample-asp-net-core-auth-issuer/blob/master/SampleAuthIssuer/wwwroot/index.html#L59-L82) with IdentityServer4 at least.

Main difference is that it uses another `Content-Type` (`x-www-form-urlencoded`), which I thought [is mandatory per RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3.2) or at least the suggested mode. I'm not sure why your postman screenshot would work then though...

Comment: Thanks. Which flow is the recommend currently?

Comment: For public browser clients I believe (per 2020-08) the OpenID "Authorization Code" with PKCE [is recommended](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics-12.html#rfc.section.3).

Comment: Unfortunately I saw that `Authorization Code` flow is also deprecated into Spring Security Oauth2. I can't find right now the link for that. Alternatives?

Comment: Not sure what to say. Are you sure that AuthCode _with_ PKCE is deprecated? Either way, if your Auth Server solution deprecates a flow, I think it's best to also follow _their_ advice on an alternative? What does Spring Security Oauth2 recommend for public JS clients?

Answer (score 0):

```
autoGenerateToken() {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({});

    const body = new URLSearchParams();
    body.set('grant_type', 'password');
    body.set('username', `${this.apiConfig.getUsername()}`);
    body.set('password', `${this.apiConfig.getPassword()}`);

    return this.http.post(this.apiConfig.getOAuthUrl(), body.toString(), {
      headers,
    });
  }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).